# Is the only way to do this an inline if statement?

Tags: jquery

```
var filterMinPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:first').val();
var filterMaxPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:last').val();
```

Currently they are set to an empty string if the input box is empty.  I log these values currently with console.log.

Is it possible to give these values the value of "NULL", the only way I can see of doing this is possibly putting the if statement inside of the val().  But is there a better way perhaps some chaining function I am missing?

So if the input box has a value I want it assigned to the var.  If it is an empty string I want "NULL" assigned to the var.

Hope I explained that well enough!

Comment: Why cant you just check the var before you log it? Check if its empty string and change it to 'NULL'

Comment: @jzworkman trying to conserve line space in code.  This is already a pretty big function, and having to check these two variables along with about 20 others would just be too much meat for me.

Comment: You can see my answer below, add an inline check to where you log the data if you  want it to use the variable and not have to make two jquery calls in the line.

Comment: Thank you all for the super quick and correct answers.  You all help make me a better programmer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filterMinPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:first').val() || null;
var filterMaxPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:last').val() || null;
```

Not that it helps anything as you still need to test for `null` somewhere and you might as well test for the empty string instead.

You might wanna avoid querying the same element sets for this complex selector twice by:

```
var inputs =  $('.hidePVVol > td input'),
    filterMinPV = inputs.first().val() || null,
    filterMaxPV = inputs.last().val() || null;
```

Comment: If the value is the string '0', wouldn't that set the value to null?

Comment: No, because only the empty string is a falsy value `!!'0'
//true
!!''
//false`

Comment: Much better than PHP, then. :)

Comment: Although, the number 0 will fail.

Comment: The result of `.val` is a `String`, not a parsed `Number`

Comment: @Esailija I like this version better, even less code!  I also learned something about setting vars up.

Comment: @Esailija I actually pass in the null value directly into a sql stored procedure.  It recognizes it as NULL and knows to ignore it.  I supposed I could have checked to see if the param was empty, I just think NULL is more friendly, nothing more than a personal choice I guess.

Comment: @Esailija thanks for the alternative suggestions, I implemented it.  I always love cleaner code. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you log the values:

```
logger.log(filterMinPV == '' ? filterMinPV : 'NULL');
logger.log(filterMaxPV == '' ? filterMaxPV : 'NULL');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filterMinPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:first').val() !== '' ? $('.hidePVVol > td input:first').val() : null;
var filterMaxPV = $('.hidePVVol > td input:last').val() !== '' ? $('.hidePVVol > td input:last').val() : null;
```

Comment: :) I like in-line conditionals.

Comment: @MichaelRushton I don't understand how that works, but I'm glad it does.  What does the ? do.  Going to try and find it on jquery.com.  Thank you again

Comment: Its the inline conditional operator.  The condition is the statement before the `?`, the true option is before the `:` while the false option is after

Comment: `variable = [condition] ? [if true] : [if false]`

Comment: Ahh thank you both, I did not know that that was even possible until now. :)

Comment: @JosephSilber Is what I am doing in my above post a bad way to do it?  I know the DOM is expensive, am I making a poor decision in the way I am setting up vars?  I don't know much about how taxing certain calls are.

Comment: You are making two separate calls to the dom doing it this way.  my answer below shows how you can do it when you log the results instead and just have to reference that var. And the one above by @Esailija is an even cleaner approach

Comment: Does `variable = (value = $('#id').val()) !== '' ? value : null;` suffer the same problem?

Comment: I dont believe so, but you will still be making two calls(one for each var) so making a single call to the dom and storing that value would still be better(like @Esailija did above)

Comment: @MichaelRushton - That would create a global variable named `value`. You shouldn't be doing that.